# The server tag is not well formed?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am getting the above error. I want to validate the textbox which allow some special characters but not letters and numbers. For that I wrote the below code but it is giving the above error.

The code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTag" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reg1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtTag" ErrorMessage="*" Text="please check" 
    ValidationExpression="/^[[\]'/\\@ &(){}+$%#=~"-`/*.&]([[\]'/\\@ &(){}+$%#=~"-`/*.&]*)$/" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes in the `ValidationExpression` with `&quot;`:

```
ValidationExpression="/^[[\]'/\\@ &(){}+$%#=~&quot;-/*.&]([[]'/\@ &(){}+$%#=~&quot;-/*.&]*)$/"
```

They collide with the outer quotes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/^[[\]'/\\@ &amp;(){}+$%#=~&quot;-/*.&amp;]([[]'/\@ &amp;(){}+$%#=~&quot;-/*.&amp;]*)$/
```

as `ValidationExpression`.